# Unable to import AFNetworking dependency into Cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to setup the podspec for my project and I keep getting this error when I run `pod spec lint`

```
➭ pod spec lint

 -> BRECBathroomFinder (1.0.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
    - ERROR |  BRECBathroomFinder/BRECBathroomFinder/BBFOpenDataClient.swift:16:26: error: use of undeclared type 'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager'
    - ERROR | [iOS]  BRECBathroomFinder/BRECBathroomFinder/BBFOpenDataClient.swift:29:73: error: use of undeclared type 'AFHTTPRequestOperation'
    - ERROR | [iOS]  BRECBathroomFinder/BRECBathroomFinder/BBFOpenDataClient.swift:48:35: error: use of undeclared type 'AFHTTPRequestOperation'
    - NOTE  | [iOS]  }, failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    - ERROR | [iOS]  BRECBathroomFinder/BRECBathroomFinder/BBFOpenDataClient.swift:29:9: error: 'BBFOpenDataClient' does not have a member named 'GET'

Analyzed 1 podspec.
```

Here is my podspec. You'll notice at the bottom that my I've got `.prefix_header_contents = "#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>"` in there; so it doesn't make sense to me that it can't find the AFHTTPRequestOperation class.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s| 
  s.name = "BRECBathroomFinder"
  s.version = "1.0.0"
  s.summary = "A pod that finds nearby BREC parks with restrooms"
  s.description = <<-DESC
                  This is a project built on top of Baton Rouge's Open Data API. It uses a query to find parks with bathrooms.

                  The results can be sorted according to how close the parks are to a given location or the user's location.
                  DESC
  s.homepage = "https://github.com/jmhooper/BRECBathroomFinder"
  s.author = { "Jonathan Hooper" => "jon9820@gmail.com"  }
  s.license = 'MIT'
  s.source = { git: "https://github.com/jmhooper/BRECBathroomFinder.git", tag: s.version.to_s }
  s.platform = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.source_files = "BRECBathroomFinder/**/*"
  s.dependency "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
  s.frameworks = "CoreLocation"
  s.prefix_header_contents = "#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of frustration I finally figured it out.

In the file it was complaining about, I had to add a `import AFNetworking` line along with the rest of my Swift imports.

I did that and the podspec passed validation.

Comment: I started receiving this error only after adding `use_frameworks` to my Podfile